# Microsoft Publisher: Mac Equivalent?

Tags: software-recommendation, ms-office, switching

[Microsoft Publisher](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/publisher/) is an excellent piece of software on Windows. Does a Mac equivalent of Microsoft Publisher exist in its own entity ?

Comment: What specifically is excellent? What features do you need? To avoid a recommendation question from being closed, there is a [meta] post on how to document the requirements. https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2180/how-should-i-ask-about-getting-a-software-recommendation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A suitable alternative maybe seen in [iStudio Publisher](http://www.istudiopublisher.com/), an easy-to-use page layout application for desktop publishing on Mac, allowing the creation of professional quality documents with ease, including newsletters, brochures, adverts to name but a few.

[Video tutorials](http://www.istudiopublisher.com/video-tutorials/) & a [rapid start guide](http://www.istudiopublisher.com/support/help-pages/) also aid novices to the most experienced of users.

It is considered an excellent resource for those who bemoan the fact that MS Publisher is not available on the Mac platform.

From Apple's [App store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/istudio-publisher/id430820689?mt=12) it is $17.99. Purchasing directly from the website above however gives a 30 day free trial period.

Answer (score 8):

What exactly are you trying to create?
You may be going to great expense and, yet be able to accomplish what you need with [Pages](http://www.apple.com/mac/pages/). Pages is available on the Mac App Store and quite robust.

Answer (score 4):

If you want a full list of Publisher alternatives for Mac, [this may be helpful](http://alternativeto.net/software/microsoft-publisher/?platform=mac).  I've seen Apple Pages produce some nice documents though it may be more simplistic than Publisher in many respects.

If you are open to a web-based option, our product [Lucidpress](http://www.lucidpress.com) may serve you well since you can use it on any platform.

Comment: Uh, if Publisher isn't simplistic, I don't know what is.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to vote for [QuarkXpress](http://www.quark.com/Products/QuarkXPress/#1) as a replacement for Publisher. Serious pros either use InDesign or QuarkXpress, and the latter has the advantage of not requiring a subscription fee, as Adobe products do. It's not as cheap as iStudio Publisher, but it's much more feature-rich. As they say, you get what you pay for.

Answer (score 2):

You can open Publisher files on Mac using a conversion tool and then convert the .pub file to PDF and open it that way. MS Word also has a Publishing Layout View function which is similar to Publisher. However, for the best alternative, I think Pages does a pretty god job although it's more like Word. For Pros, go with Adobe InDesign. This is a pretty good article on [alternatives to Publisher on Mac](http://machow2.com/publisher-for-mac/) too.

Answer (score 1):

No one has pointed out here that although there is no version of Publisher for Mac, some of the functionality of Publisher is available in Word for Mac by selecting the "Publishing Layout View". However, it is nowhere near as functional as Publisher and you're definitely better-off using one of the many excellent [Publisher alternatives on Mac](http://machow2.com/publisher-for-mac/) particularly InDesign or Quark.

Answer (score 0):

The Best option is definitely [InDesign](http://www.adobe.com/ca/products/indesign.html). But it's also probably the most expensive one.

It's the reference in Desktop publishing software.

Additional information:

[Adobe InDesign](http://www.adobe.com/products/indesign.html) is available for Windows and Macintosh. It is a high-end industry standard program used by the publishing industry for producing all kinds of documents up to and including internationally-renowned newspapers and magazines. At this time it is only available by a $50 per month subscription to Adobe's Creative Cloud service. Needless to say, it is much more powerful and advanced than Microsoft Publisher, which is designed for low-end office and small-business newsletter production.

Comment: I guess all Apple products command a premium. Is it possible to provide appropriate link in your answer.

Comment: It's worth some explanation as to why InDesign is a better replacement for Publisher than another "desktop publishing" app, such as Apple's Pages.

Comment: Pages is a word processing software and InDesign is a Desktop Publishing software like Publisher. Publisher might be a good software but it's not available on OSX.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write try [Apache OpenOffice](https://www.openoffice.org).

Comment: This is not spam. It is a legitimate attempt to offer software on a question asking for that recommendation. I'm not saying it's right (or wrong) or you should vote one way to the other, but please there's no need to flag this again. If anything, the question should be voted to be closed since it's not following our guidance on asking a proper recommendation question. +1 for the attempt to answer Harrison

Answer (score 0):

You may also try Swift Publisher from BeLight Software, available in [Mac App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/swift-publisher-4/id1014507510?mt=12) or from their [web site](https://www.swiftpublisher.com/) (a free trial is available).